# How to show drop down menu of the AutoCompleteTextView when text has changed?

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried some variants, one of them:

```
tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    tv.showDropDown();
  }
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
});
```

But, dropdown suggestions shows and hides at once (looks like blink). Is there any way to show drop down after editing text?

Also I added a button (for the test) and added an onclick listener to it, which calls `tv.showDropDown();` method and it works well, how I have expected (it means (IMHO) that there is no problems in BaseAdapter, Filter, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you must be doing all this.. autocomplete should be like automatic..

as in you must just tell it the data that it has to use for autocomplete and voilla you are done. You need not manually do `tv.showDropDown()`

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where `COUNTRIES` is an array of string

look here http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html

Comment: I use a custom BaseAdapter and Filter (and it doesn't show automatically).

Comment: then you should be looking at why doesn't it show automatically.. look through your xml.. if you still don't figure it out post xml

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html .. it says api v1

Answer (score 1):

Look @ my answer.. It's very simple hack by resetting text when you get updated data...

```
autoRailwayFrom.setText(autoRailwayFrom.getText());
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15044017/1136023